# JAXB - How to set xmlns and prefix in child tag only

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb

I'm using JAXB to generate a soap xml request. The current xml output that i want is this

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:rgw="http:/blablablablabla.org" 
xmlns:typ="http://blablablablabla.org/bla/bla">

<soapenv:Header>

  <wsse:Security 
  soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" 
  xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
  xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">

       <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="testToken-13">
        <wsse:Username>blbalbalL</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password 
        Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">1234r</wsse:Password>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
 </soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Until now i have generate the Envelope and Header tag but i have trouble with the Security tag.

My problem is if i try to set the xmlns to package-info.class the prefix is correct but the `xmlns:wsse="blbalbla"` and the `xmlns:wsu="http://balbla.com"` going to the root element(envelope) and not into the security tag. Here is the output that i get:

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:rgw="http://gr/gsis/rgwsalldata/RgWsAllData.wsdl" 
xmlns:typ="http://gr/gsis/rgwsalldata/RgWsAllData.wsdl/types/" 
xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security/>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body/>
```

As you can see in the desire xml output the `xmlns:wsse` and `xmlns:wsu` namespaces are at the security tag. how can i these xmlns to security tag? and how can the UsernameToken tag should build?

package-info.class

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
    xmlns = { @XmlNs(prefix="soapenv", namespaceURI="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"),
              @XmlNs(prefix="rgw", namespaceURI="http://blabalbalbal.org"),
              @XmlNs(prefix="typ", namespaceURI="blablaba/types/"),
              @XmlNs(prefix="wsse", namespaceURI="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"),
              @XmlNs(prefix="wsu", namespaceURI="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd")},
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)

package broker.jaxb.xmlrequest;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

Comment: Why do you want to move the namespace declaration?  The XML documents are equivalent.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan i dont have a lot of experience with jaxb and xml files and i want to move the namespace declaration inorder to generate exactly the same soap xml request so that i can be sure that i wont get any errors causing by the namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @XmlType(namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss") (or XMLRoot) on top of Security class instead of declaring the namespace in package-info it should bring the namespace down to the Security tag.

As mentioned in the comment both documents are equivalent xml, so first test if the soap message works as it is. No point in reproducing the exact format if the other side can read this one as well (any decent modern WS framework will do).

Comment: intresting but i cant have the desired  prefix that way. i get a ns5 prefix on every child tag of Security. `@XmlType(name = "Security", namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd") 
public class Security` and it doesn't bring the namespace to the securty tag

Comment: thanks! i will leave the namespace as it is as long as they are quivalent.

Comment: If that does "work", it is a fluke as that is not how the `@XmlType` annotation is intended to be interpreted.